# Clip the background except the image in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a pattern that looks like this: 
[image]

A border line split by an 'or'.

Following is my code.

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/pattern-03.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1:after {
  content: 'Or';
  padding: 20px;
  top: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: -7px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ccc;
}
#div2 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">

  <div id="div1">

  </div>
  <div id="div2">

  </div>

</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to remove the part of line from the perimeter of the `div1:after` - the `div` that contains 'or', is there a way to achieve this in css with this markup ?

Comment: There are no borders on my side. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: Have edited the question. Please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split line to two elements and move them away from "or":

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/pattern-03.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40px;
}
#div1 span {
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
#div1:before,
#div1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 19px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#div1:before {
  top: -20px;
}
#div1:after {
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div id="div1"><span>OR</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May not be the right answer, but can help you get started. An workaround

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  background: url(http://www.noupe.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/pattern-03.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
#div1 {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  height: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
#div1:after {
  content: 'Or';
  padding: 20px;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 0px;
  margin-right: -7px;
  color: #fff;
}
#div2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  height: 40%;
  position: relative;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div id="div1">

  </div>
  <div id="div2">

  </div>
</div>
```